# Why does hostname -i give different results on different machines?

Tags: hostname

On machine a I run

```
hostname -i
```

and I get:

```
10.42.16.40
```

On machine b I run

```
hostname -i
```

and I get:

```
fe80::4a0:3bff:fed8:ef09%eth0 10.42.16.32
```

All I want is the IP address

My question is: **Why does hostname -i give different results on different machines?**

EDIT

Both machines give the same

```
> type hostname
hostname is hashed (/usr/bin/hostname)
```

Comment: see if it aliased to something else.. like `type hostname`

Comment: On my system, `-i` isn't even a valid option for `hostname`.

Comment: @muru On my Ubuntu 14.04, `hostname` (comes with `hostname` package) has it.

Comment: @heemayl sure it may, but OP hasn't specified an OS and I'm on OSX at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hostname -i` reads the `/etc/hosts` file, and gets you the IP address `hostname` is set as.

For example, if your `hostname` is `foobar`, and `/etc/hosts` has:

```
10.42.16.40 foobar
```

then, `hostname -i` will give:

```
10.42.16.40
```

---

Also look at `hostname -I` to enumerate all IP addresses of all configured network interfaces (except loopback, and IPv6 link local) of the host.

Comment: Second bit sorted it